# Prevent Simulink codegen copying variable literals

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am generating C code of a simple simulink model that uses the "From Workspace" block to input a timetable.  In the resulting C code the literal array data I used is copied into the code.  I imagine using a regex to remove it but that's not very clean.  Is there a way to prevent this from being copied? Am I using the wrong block for this?

Another question is if there is something better to use than From Workspace block since this results in codegen model check warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can load data into Simulink using input ports, if you already have run a matlab script and therefore have the data in your workspace.

However I don't really know if this produces a cleaner output in the C generated code. Hope this helps, I add a [link to the official mathwork page](https://it.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/load-data-to-root-level-input-ports-1.html) on input ports.